# Cordova IOS 7.1 Calendar is read only.

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, calendar, ios7.1

We are using cordova to built cross platform app. Calendars were getting saved in ios 7.0 and prior. In the newest version it gives error. Calendar could not found while creating calendar, if we create calendar manually using iphone calendar application, than we get calendar is read only error.

We are using calendar plugin of EddyVerbruggen.

```
var startDate = new Date(2014,10,1,18,30,0,0,0);
var endDate = new Date(2014,10,30,19,30,0,0,0);
var title = tempItem.name;
var location = "Home";
var notes = tempItem.description;

var success = function(message) { alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(message)); };
var error = function(message) { alert("Error: " + message); };

var createCalOptions = window.plugins.calendar.getCreateCalendarOptions();
createCalOptions.calendarName = "Calendar";
createCalOptions.calendarColor = "#FF0000"; // an optional hex color (with the # char), default is null, so the OS picks a color
window.plugins.calendar.createCalendar(createCalOptions,success,error);
window.plugins.calendar.createEventInNamedCalendar(title,location,notes,startDate,endDate,"Calendar",success,error);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by not giving calendar name while saving events. Now the events are getting save in default calendar.